# Add OR clause in AND clause in SF2 queryBuilder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, query-builder

I would like to do a request like that in the SF2 query builder:

```
SELECT *
FROM `annonce` a 
LEFT JOIN `ville` v ON a.ville_id=v.id 
WHERE a.titre LIKE '%s%' AND (v.cp LIKE '94%' OR v.nomComplet='alf%')
```

But i don't know how to include the OR clause in the AND clause. Currently i have that :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->select('a')
                ->leftJoin('a.ville', 'v');
        $qb->where($qb->expr()->like('a.titre', ':titre'))
                ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('v.cp', ':lieu'))
                ->OrWhere($qb->expr()->like('v.nomComplet', ':lieu'))
                ->setParameter('titre', '%' . $item . '%')
                ->setParameter('lieu', $lieu . '%')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

But this is not the correct implementation. I need to have the OrWhere IN the AndWhere

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is [orX condition](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

```
$qb->expr()->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->like('v.cp', ':lieu'),
        $qb->expr()->like('v.nomComplet', ':lieu')
    )
)
```